# UIScrollView displays first image fine but subsequent images zoom and pan incorrectly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have app that pulls in images from Flickr and they can be selected and displayed in a UIScrollView with zooming an panning enabled. The first image I select is fine, panning and zooming works as expected. Any image I load after the first one however does not behave correctly. Panning is limited and when I zoom it the first time it always resets the image to the top left corner of the screen and again panning is very limited, it does zoom however. Here is the method:

```
-(void)loadImageFromURLandSetupScrollView{

[self startToolbarActivityIndicator];
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    UIImage *imageFromFlickr = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.photoURL]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.photo.image = imageFromFlickr;
        self.photo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.photo.image.size.width, self.photo.image.size.height);
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.photo.bounds.size;

        //setup the zoom scale to show best possible
        float zoomScaleWidth = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width / self.photo.image.size.width;
        float zoomScaleHeight = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height / self.photo.image.size.height;

        if(zoomScaleHeight < zoomScaleWidth){
            self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = zoomScaleHeight;
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = zoomScaleWidth;
        }
        else{
            self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = zoomScaleWidth; //make sure it can't be zoomed less than longest side at full screen
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = zoomScaleHeight;
        }
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10;

        //set scroll view background colour
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self stopToolBarActivityMonitor];
    });
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems this is something caused by the new auto layout feature, the work around I went with is to not have a UIImageView in the story board but instead to programatically add it to the scroll view when needed.

```
-(UIImageView *)photo
{
if (!_photo) _photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
return _photo;
}

-(void)loadImageFromURLandSetupScrollView{
[self startToolbarActivityIndicator];
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr downloader", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    UIImage *imageFromFlickr = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.photoURL]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.photo.image = imageFromFlickr;

        [self.scrollView addSubview:self.photo];
        // Set the min and max:
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
        self.scrollView.delegate = self;

        // Set the content:
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0; // reset zoomScale for new image
        self.scrollView.contentSize = self.photo.image.size;
        self.photo.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.photo.image.size.width, self.photo.image.size.height);

        //setup the zoom scale to show best possible
        float zoomScaleWidth = self.scrollView.bounds.size.width / self.photo.image.size.width;
        float zoomScaleHeight = self.scrollView.bounds.size.height / self.photo.image.size.height;

        if(zoomScaleHeight < zoomScaleWidth)
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = zoomScaleWidth;
        else
            self.scrollView.zoomScale = zoomScaleHeight;

        //set scroll view background colour
        self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self stopToolBarActivityMonitor];
    });
});
}
```